# How to find stock price at a certain time with yfinance?

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

I am trying to find the stock price at a certain time with python. I am using the `yfinance`
package to do this. When I run the code:

```
ticker = yf.Ticker(row['ticker'])
print('datetime_object', datetime_object)
final_time = datetime_object + timedelta(minutes=15)
print('Final Time (15 minutes after given time ): ', final_time)
end_price = ticker.history(start=datetime_object, end=final_time, interval='1m')
```

This is my result:

```
datetime_object 2022-01-24 19:49:25+00:00
Final Time (15 minutes after given time ):  2022-01-24 20:04:25+00:00
- NFLX: Data doesn't exist for startDate = 1643071765, endDate = 1643072665
end_price Empty DataFrame
```

It says there is currently no data available for that certain time. Is there a better library that I can use that has access to recent stock historicals?

Comment: @GoldenLion thank you for the response however this is the error I receive `NFLX: Invalid input - interval=1min is not supported. Valid intervals: [1m, 2m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 60m, 90m, 1h, 1d, 5d, 1wk, 1mo, 3mo]`

Comment: I think the package is broken.  Not all the functionality works.  rio = yf.Ticker("RIO")
bhp=yf.Ticker('BHP')
hist = rio.history(period="5y") work

Comment: @GoldenLion thank you for the input... what package would you recommend for this situation

Comment: https://analyticsindiamag.com/top-python-libraries-to-get-historical-stock-data-with-code/  yfinance is preferred by most

Comment: @GoldenLion yes it is unfortunate that it is broken... I will try TwelveData

Answer (score 0):

This code does not work because Yahoo finance provides the stock value down to the minute not the second. Also, the results include `[start_time, end_time)`, so you must provide 1 day ahead for the results for the current day.